# A simple little Python web crawler

Tags: python, multithreading, http, web-scraping

The crawler is in need of a mechanism that will dispatch threads based on network latency and system load. How does one keep track of network latency
in Python without using system tools like ping?

```
import sys
import re
import urllib2
import urlparse
import requests
import socket
import threading
import gevent
from gevent import monkey
import time

monkey.patch_all(
  socket=True,
  dns=True,
  time=True,
  select=True,
  thread=True,
  os=True,
  ssl=True,
  httplib=False,
  subprocess=False,
  sys=False,
  aggressive=True,
  Event=False)

# The  stack
tocrawl = set([sys.argv[1]])
crawled = set([])
linkregex = re.compile('<a\s*href=[\'|"](.*?)[\'"].*?>')

def Update(links):
  if links != None:
    for link in (links.pop(0) for _ in xrange(len(links))):
      link = ( "http://%s" %(urlparse.urlparse(link).netloc) )
      if link not in crawled:
        tocrawl.add(link)

def getLinks(crawling):
  crawled.add(crawling)
  try:
    Update(linkregex.findall(requests.get(crawling).content))
  except:
    return None

def crawl():
  try:
    print"%d Threads running" % (threading.activeCount())
    crawling = tocrawl.pop()
    print crawling
    print len(crawled)
    walk = gevent.spawn(getLinks,crawling)
    walk.run()
  except:quit()

def dispatcher():
  while True:
    T = threading.Thread(target=crawl)
    T.start()
    time.sleep(1)

dispatcher()
```

Comment: The idea is to hit n domains and after n domains
have been hit stop crawling and check each domain
in the set of crawled domains for rss feeds

Comment: Rolled back Rev 5 → 2. Please don't edit code in the question after it has been answered; you have several [options](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763) for follow-ups.

Answer (score 8):

I see a flurry of downloading activity, but I don't see that you do anything with the pages that you download except parse some URLs for more downloading.  There's no rate limiting or any attempt to check [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org), making your web crawler a poor Internet citizen.

[PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) mandates four spaces per level of indentation.  Since whitespace is significant in Python, you should stick to the convention.  Furthermore, function names should be `lower_case()`, so `Update()` and `getLinks()` should be renamed.

Just a simple call to `gevent.monkey.patch_all()` will do.  There is no need to `from gevent import monkey`, nor is there any need to list all of the keyword parameters, since you're accepting all of the defaults.

Your `linkregex` fails if the `<a>` tag contains any intervening attributes before `href`.  For example, `<a target="_blank" href="…">` will cause a link to be skipped.

I don't believe that your code is a well behaved multithreaded program.  For one thing, you indiscriminately spawn and start one thread per second.  If the average processing time per request exceeds one second, you'll end up with an uncontrolled proliferation of threads.

Another issue is that you `add()` and `pop()` `tocrawl` elements without any kind of locking.  Also, if one thread fails to `pop()` anything (probably when the `tocrawl` list becomes empty), you rudely call `quit()` without giving other threads a chance to finish what they are doing.

Finally, you process the URLs using a stack.  Web crawling is usually done using a queue, to avoid processing clusters of closely related URLs together and concentrating the load on one unfortunate webserver at a time.